# SwiftUI: Clear current user auth uid when testing an app

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

New to swift and i'm trying to test the login functions on an app I'm trying to make but I cant seem to get the app to "log out" and act as a first time user.

Have this little bit of code to check the login status, but it keeps giving me my auth uid. Im using sign in with apple and firebase

Before I run it I clean the build folder, delete the user from firebase, delete the app from my phone, and make sure the app has been removed from the "Apps using apple id" setting. But it still prints out the auth id when I run it on my phone.

```
 .onAppear(perform: {
            Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
                    if user != nil {
                        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {
                            showLogin = false
                            print("on appear auth id")
                            print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
                        }else{
                            showLogin = true
                        }
                    } else {
                        showLogin = true
                    }
            }
        })
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showLogin, content: Login.init)
```

Comment: Why not use the Firebase `signOut` function?

Comment: Yeah I feel like an idiot for not just doing that. I figured doing all I listed would be like signing for the first time but I didn't realize there would be some hangup somewhere along the line still.